# How to play a sound every time we have a new customer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest

"At first, there were a half-dozen orders per day. One of the programmers set up the computers so that a bell would ring every time an order came in."
- The Rise of Jeff Bezos and Amazon.com

I want to do this, but figure there has to be a "smart and get things done" way of doing this that is almost effortless.

I would it to basically be an existing API, that we could put in our ASP.NET MVC application and would on one of our machines make the sound happen.

I can code it from scratch, but feel like at least some of the parts should be available.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at first you will need a bell, or a speaker to play a bell sound. Then you'll need some piece of code or a program to ring that bell. Now you need to find a way to communicate between your bell ringing program and your Shop. You can do this over sockets, pipes or something else. Since you're using Asp.net you could use some .Net Code to call Windows Media Player or something.

```
Sub Play()
        Try
            Dim mplayer As New Media.SoundPlayer
            mplayer.SoundLocation = Server.MapPath("1.wav")
            mplayer.Load()
            mplayer.Play()
            mplayer.Dispose()
            errormessage.Text = "PLD_KNTR_OK"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

this would only work if your server is near you and it has a sound card, ofc.
otherwise, use some of the methods i've described above.

Answer (score 1):

This won't ring an actual bell in your shop, but you could try BellBot. I had the same desire and was searching for a solution. I want to ring an actual bell on my wall, but this may suit your needs.

You insert the line of code onto a thank you page or something the user hits when they first sign up, and then as long as you have the website open at the time your computer will sound off with a semi-goofy bell sound. It's free as well.

The website is here: http://www.bellbot.com/

Comment: I made Bellbot. Thanks!